# BindableProperty in custom view does not unsubscribe PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Background info**

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms (v4.1.1.3, testing on iOS) application in XAML, using MVVM with a *View first* approach; I'm assigning single-instance ViewModels to Views by using the ViewModelLocator service of MVVMLight:

```
BindingContext="{Binding [SearchViewModel], Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
```

When navigating to another page, I'm constructing a new instance of the page, which will receive the very same ViewModel instance every time.

```
var page = new SearchView();
var tabbedPage = Application.Current.MainPage as TabbedPage;
if (tabbedPage != null)
    await tabbedPage.CurrentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
```

**The issue**

I've implemented a custom control (view?), that is supposed to show search results in a tile-like layout. This control is created when navigating from a search `NavigationPage` to a search results `ContentPage`.

Every time I return to the search page and navigate back to search results, the view is reconstructed and the `PropertyChanged` of the `BindableProperties` are subscribed. These `PropertyChanged` events are never unsubscribed, so every time I navigate to the search results view and change the bound ViewModel property, the event is fired increasingly multiple times.

In the following code the `OnItemsPropertyChanged` is triggered multiple times, based on how many times I've navigated from the search view to the search results view:

```
public class WrapLayout : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Items", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(WrapLayout), null, propertyChanged: OnItemsPropertyChanged);

    public IEnumerable Items
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public WrapLayout()
    {
        ...
    }

    private static void OnItemsPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

*My questions:*

- Shouldn't the `BindableProperty` unsubscribe from `PropertyChanged` and `-Changing` by itself?
- Does this occur because of the way I associated Views with ViewModels and/or navigate through pages?
- Should I handle unsubscribing these events myself, and how?

**EDIT; additional navigation info**

I have a `MainView` `TabbedPage`, which creates `SearchView` as `NavigationPage`:

```
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Children.Add(new NavigationPage(new SearchView())
    {
        Title = AppResources.Tab_Search,
        Icon = "tab_search"
    });
}
```

`SearchView` has, upon creation, a single-instance ViewModel assigned by the `ViewModelLocator` that was mentioned at the start of this topic, using MVVMLight's `SimpleIoc` container.

When a search command in `SearchView` is fired, I send a request to an API which returns search results. These results are displayed on another page, to which I navigate to from the `SearchView`'s ViewModel:

```
await _navigationService.NavigateTo(ViewModelLocator.PageKeyFileResults, searchResult);
```

Which functionality looks somewhat like this:

```
public async Task NavigateTo(string pagekey, object viewModelParameter)
{
    var constructor = _pagesByKey[pagekey].Constructor; //Gets the Func<Page> that simple creates the requested page, without using reflection.

    var page = constructor() as Page;

    var viewModel = page.BindingContext as BaseViewModel;
    if (viewModel != null)
        viewModel.Initialize(viewModelParameter);

    var tabbedPage = Application.Current.MainPage as TabbedPage;
    if (tabbedPage != null)
        await tabbedPage.CurrentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
    else
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

The constructed page looks somewhat like:

```
<pages:BaseContentPage 
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  x:Class="Views.FileResultsView"
  xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Views.Pages;assembly=Views"
  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Views.Controls;assembly=Views"
  BindingContext="{Binding [FileResultsViewModel], Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
  <ScrollView>
    <controls:WrapLayout
      Items="{Binding SearchResults}" />
  </ScrollView>
</pages:BaseContentPage>
```

Where BaseContentPage is:

```
public class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<DialogMessage>(this, "ShowDialog", (dialogMessage) =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dialogMessage.AcceptButton))
                DisplayAlert(dialogMessage.Title, dialogMessage.Content, dialogMessage.CancelButton);
            else
                DisplayAlert(dialogMessage.Title, dialogMessage.Content, dialogMessage.AcceptButton, dialogMessage.CancelButton);
        });
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<DialogMessage>(this, "ShowDialog");
    }
}
```

And where ViewModel is basically like this:

```
public class FileResultsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private IEnumerable<ASRow> _searchResults;

    public IEnumerable<ASRow> SearchResults
    {
        get { return _searchResults; }
        set { Set(ref _searchResults, value); }
    }

    internal override void Initialize(object parameter)
    {
        base.Initialize(parameter);

        if (parameter is AdvancedSearchResponse)
        {
            var searchResults = parameter as AdvancedSearchResponse;
            SearchResults = new List<ASRow>(searchResults.Rows);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Shouldn't the BindableProperty unsubscribe from PropertyChanged and -Changing by itself?

No. The `Binding` class takes care of this. Not the `BindableProperty`.

- Does this occur because of the way I associated Views with ViewModels and/or navigate through pages?

You are seeing this because you are forgetting that the Navigation Stack keeps a list of pages in memory. Since multiple pages are pointing to the same BindingContext, there are multiple observers to changes. You would not have this particular issue if you didn't re-use View Models.

- Should I handle unsubscribing these events myself, and how?

No. If it is really a concern then set `BindingContext` to `null` when a page disappears, and then restore it when reappearing. Keep in mind though that this still has cost to it, especially if your UI is really busy and has lots of dynamic content that is controlled by data bindings.

Comment: Thanks, I might just use single instance Views in that case (although that isn't quite MVVM), or just redesign the entire architecture... I guess the retainment of pages by the navigation stack is the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

- Shouldn't the BindableProperty unsubscribe from PropertyChanged and -Changing by itself?

  - Yes - it should. If it does not it is most certainly a bug
- Does this occur because of the way I associated Views with ViewModels and/or navigate trough pages?

  - That is most likely also an option, since i didn't experience the behaviour you described yet. You would need to share more of your surrounding setup code.
- Should I handle unsubscribing these events myself, and how?

  - It's hard for you to always control unsubscribing, since most of the time it will be the control subscribing to events (unless you do it yourself, in which case it's always your duty to unsub again)

While it is ugly it's sometimes necessary to get a quick workaround, which in your case would be browsing how xamarin holds a list of the change delegates and manually unsubscribe them on page appearing for example.

I hope that answers your question. Feel free to comment if it does not.

#### Update

In your case i would debug your page base, and verify wether or not

- OnDisappearing is called correctly
- Your handler is gone after unsubscribe
- (This is lazy but i usually unsub an event before subbing it, just to make sure such a bug does not happen, because most EventManagement services won't throw if you're trying to unsub a handler which is not registered.)

at least that's the most likely causes of your issue.

Comment: If it's not default behavior, I'd like to find a solution indeed, before I build in counter measurements. I've appended the entire navigation that takes place from MainView to SearchResult. Perhaps you could have a look, maybe identify possible causes?

Comment: @hantoun Yes, i'll see what i can do. heading for a break now. And yeah - trying to get a proper solution is usually the most desirable option :)

Comment: @hantoun Updated, feel free to verify whether or not that fixes it

Comment: The MessagingCenter seems to be subscribing and unsubscribing as supposed to; even so, this MessagingCenter implementation is brandnew. When I modified my ticket I noticed that the `BaseContentPage` was passing itself to the ViewModel, which does not comply with MVVM guidelines. I thought it might have caused the main issue. After I implemented the MessagingCenter, nothing had changed about the problem.

Comment: @Sjeijoet unfortunately brand new does not mean it works without bugs. I've used TemplatedView and had quite some fun with bugs too, only to be told that they won't change it atm for backwards compatibility, just after feature release. To me Xamarin.Forms is still in a public beta stage :/ One can only hope MS will clean up this poor quality mess